# Is this ringworm?

Tags: dogs

Lesion appeared over the snout about a week ago. Have been applying anti fungal cream but no change to the lesion. It’s been the same size for the last few days. Does not appear to be itchy or sore. [image]!

Comment: The lesion appears raised and doesn’t really look like tinea to me; especially if it’s not itchy. The ineffectiveness of the antifungal would seem to support this not being ringworm. Are there other lesions? Has your dog behaved any differently? Eating, drinking, elimination and activity levels should be observed. I would make an appointment with your vet and have a skin scraping done for analysis. Good luck! Please let us know the outcome of the vet appointment.